# Derivation of cylindrical line heat source problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, boundary-conditions, differential-equations

I have a line heat source embedded inside a cylinder and I am trying to find the temperature distribution T(r,t). By using the similarity variable, the solution to the differential equation is 
$$\theta(\eta)=C_{1}\int_0^\eta \! \frac{e^{-u}}{u} \, \mathrm{d}u + C_{2}$$ and my boundary conditions are $-4\pi kh\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial \eta}|_{\eta=0}=q_{0}$ and $\theta\to0$ as $\eta\to\infty$.

When I apply the first boundary condition using the derivative I get $1/0$ which is indeterminate so what do I do there? Also, the second boundary condition is supposed to give the exponential integral function, but I am not sure where that comes from. I guess I am stuck on applying the boundary conditions to this.

The derivation says the final answer should be $$\theta(\eta)=\frac{-q_{0}}{4\pi h k}\int_\eta^\infty \! \frac{e^{-u}}{u} \, \mathrm{d}u$$

Comment: Do you have to do it this way? I feel like separation of variables and Bessel functions might be easier.

Comment: Unfortunately I do have to do it this way. I agree that SoV and Bessel functions would be much easier